# What is the offset of the 30s Deezer previews?

Tags: deezer

I just found out that the 30 seconds previews (played back by Deezer for non-signed-in users) do not start from the beginning of the original, but somewhere halfway. What is the exact offset of these previews? Are they the same for all songs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For songs lasting more than 1 minute, the extract is from 30sec to 1 minute,
- For songs lasting less than 1 minute, the extract is the last 30 sec from the song,
- For songs lasting less than 30sec, the extract is the full song.